# What can I do so functions don't stack?

Tags: javascript, html, function

So this a countdown timer and when I press a button the countdown start by this line : timePassed = timePassed += 1;

Now the problem is if I press another button to reset the timer the fuctions start stacking on each other and the seconds becomes faster.

i need so that all buttons work and resets the timepassed so they don't stacking...

```js
const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};

var TIME_LIMIT = 0;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;



document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;



function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}



function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}

function timer15(){
TIME_LIMIT = 901;
timePassed = 0;
timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
timerInterval = null;
remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;


  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 0;
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;

    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
    }
  }, 1000);
}


function timer30(){
  TIME_LIMIT = 1801;
  timePassed = 0;
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
  timerInterval = null;
  remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 0;
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
    }
  }, 1000);
  }

  function timer45(){
    TIME_LIMIT = 2701;
    timePassed = 0;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
    timerInterval = null;
    remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      timePassed = timePassed += 1;
      timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
      document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
        timeLeft
      );
      setCircleDasharray();
      setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);
  
      if (timeLeft === 0) {
        onTimesUp();
      }
    }, 1000);
    }

    function timer60(){
      TIME_LIMIT = 3601;
      timePassed = 0;
      timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
      timerInterval = null;
      remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
      timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timePassed = timePassed += 1;
        timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
        document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
          timeLeft
        );
        setCircleDasharray();
        setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);
    
        if (timeLeft === 0) {
          onTimesUp();
        }
      }, 1000);
      }
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    place-items: center;
  }
  
  .base-timer {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  
  .base-timer__svg {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  
  .base-timer__circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-elapsed {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke: grey;
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-remaining {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 1s linear all;
    fill-rule: nonzero;
    stroke: currentColor;
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-remaining.green {
    color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
    color: orange;
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-remaining.red {
    color: red;
  }
  
  .base-timer__label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="timer.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="timer15()" value="15 min">
    <input type="button" onclick="timer30()" value="30 min">
    <input type="button" onclick="timer45()" value="45 min">
    <input type="button" onclick="timer60()" value="60 min">

    <script src="timer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with `timePassed = timePassed += 0;` this won't actually modify the value of `timePassed` and `timePassed = timePassed += 1;` would be better written as `timePassed += 1;`

Comment: the timePassed = timePassed += 0; it was just me trying to fix the problem,i change it now,thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear intervals one by one, not having only one variable to keep a reference for it.

Added function to clear intervals and resetting them on each button click to make sure they won't overlap.

```js
const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};

var TIME_LIMIT = 0;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval15 = null;
let timerInterval30 = null;
let timerInterval45 = null;
let timerInterval60 = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;



document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;

function clearIntervals(){
  clearInterval(timerInterval15);
  clearInterval(timerInterval30);
  clearInterval(timerInterval45);
  clearInterval(timerInterval60);
}

function onTimesUp() {
  clearIntervals();
}



function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}

function timer15(){
TIME_LIMIT = 901;
timePassed = 0;
timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
clearIntervals();
remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;


  timerInterval15 = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 0;
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;

    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
    }
  }, 1000);
}


function timer30(){
  TIME_LIMIT = 1801;
  timePassed = 0;
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
  clearIntervals();
  remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
  timerInterval30 = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 0;
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
    }
  }, 1000);
  }

  function timer45(){
    TIME_LIMIT = 2701;
    timePassed = 0;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
    clearIntervals();
    remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
    timerInterval45 = setInterval(() => {
      timePassed = timePassed += 1;
      timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
      document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
        timeLeft
      );
      setCircleDasharray();
      setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);
  
      if (timeLeft === 0) {
        onTimesUp();
      }
    }, 1000);
    }

    function timer60(){
      TIME_LIMIT = 3601;
      timePassed = 0;
      timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
      clearIntervals();
      remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
      timerInterval60 = setInterval(() => {
        timePassed = timePassed += 1;
        timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
        document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
          timeLeft
        );
        setCircleDasharray();
        setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);
    
        if (timeLeft === 0) {
          onTimesUp();
        }
      }, 1000);
      }
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    place-items: center;
  }
  
  .base-timer {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  
  .base-timer__svg {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  
  .base-timer__circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-elapsed {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke: grey;
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-remaining {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 1s linear all;
    fill-rule: nonzero;
    stroke: currentColor;
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-remaining.green {
    color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
    color: orange;
  }
  
  .base-timer__path-remaining.red {
    color: red;
  }
  
  .base-timer__label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="timer.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="timer15()" value="15 min">
    <input type="button" onclick="timer30()" value="30 min">
    <input type="button" onclick="timer45()" value="45 min">
    <input type="button" onclick="timer60()" value="60 min">

    <script src="timer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it was helpful you can mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

In each timerfunction you are setting `timerInterval = null`. This will not stop or clear the previously registered interval rather only remove its reference from the `timerInterval` variable. So you have to clear interval first before setting the new time interval.

for example in your timer30 timer45 timer60 functions. clear the timerInterval first before setInterval

```
...
clearInterval(timerInterval);

timerInterval = setInterval(() => { ... }, 1000)
```